# when click, mouseleave is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hover, click

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".compartir").hover(function() {
    console.log('hover');
    var self = this;
    setTimeout($(self).addClass('ready'), 500);
  }, function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('leave');
    setTimeout($(self).removeClass('ready'), 5000);
  });
  $(".compartir a").on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).parents('.compartir').is('.ready')) {
      console.log('!ready');
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log('ready');
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.compartir {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.compartir_box .social,
.compartir_box .showSocial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.25s linear all;
}
.compartir_box .social {
  opacity: 0;
}
.compartir_box:hover .showSocial {
  opacity: 0;
}
.compartir_box:hover .social {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compartir_box">
  <div class="compartir">
    <span class="showSocial">COMPARTIR</span>
    <div class="social">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">facebook</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">twitter</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to wait untill the options are visible, because on mobile devices the hover is also a tab, and it launches the link straight away ( without the user knowing which option yet.. ) ( that's why I included the ready class )

The problem is that seems that the `ready` class is removed at the onclick ( without delay )

Do you know any workaround??

PD: I don't know why but the jquery is not defined in the snippet even that I included jQuery... :s

Comment: Please use `$(function() {` instead of `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: @mplungjan that shouldn't affect to my issue..

Comment: But this does - it is invalid syntax: `setTimeout($(this).removeClass('ready'), 5000);` - it should be `$(".compartir").hover(function() { var $that=$(this);
    console.log('hover');
    setTimeout(function() { $that.addClass('ready')}, 500);
  }`

Comment: @mplungjan could you elaborate what do you mean?

Comment: Also this is more logical: `if (!$(this).parents('.compartir').hasClass('ready')) {`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet currently your code is executed during the click handler execution not when the timeout function fires, you must wrap it in an anonymous function (or in an internal one)

Comment: Sorry guys, I just don't understand the snippet logs.. could you provide an answer editing my question? thanks!

Comment: Both `setTimeout` calls will be called.

Comment: @guest271314 any suggestion?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet What is purpose of `setTimeout` calls? What is expected result?

Comment: "I want to wait untill the options are visible, because on mobile devices the hover is also a tab, and it launches the link straight away" (on first click/tab), it was an attempt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use an anonymous function to execute in the timeout
2. Save the object to be used later. I prefer to save the jQuery object
3. clear the timeout if needed

```js
var tId;
$(function() {
  $(".compartir").hover(function() {
    console.log('hover');
    var $self = $(this);
    clearTimeout(tId);
    tId=setTimeout(function() { $self.addClass('ready')}, 500);
  }, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    console.log('leave');
    clearTimeout(tId);
    tId=setTimeout(function() { $self.removeClass('ready')}, 5000);
  });
  $(".compartir a").on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).parents('.compartir').hasClass('ready')) {
      console.log('!ready');
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log('ready');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.compartir {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.compartir_box .social,
.compartir_box .showSocial {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.25s linear all;
}
.compartir_box .social {
  opacity: 0;
}
.compartir_box:hover .showSocial {
  opacity: 0;
}
.compartir_box:hover .social {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compartir_box">
  <div class="compartir">
    <span class="showSocial">COMPARTIR</span>
    <div class="social">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">facebook</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">twitter</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```